# Where is data manipulation code in ASP.NET Web site Template in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am rather new in ASP.NET so I decided to use ASP.NET Web Site template in Visual Studio 10. I have succesfully changed database from express edition to my online server but I fail to see where is the code that drives logic behind login and membership roles in that site (It is there by default). There is no code in .cs files so there is zero possibilies for me to change the code since I can't even find it.... I see that most of the logic is in stored procedures but they still need to be called from somewhere?

Comment: Check the aspx pages for inline code

Comment: So what is your question? Are you asking us "Pls code me my webapplication" or what?

Comment: My understanding is that this is very common template and that people that use it will immediately know the answer and write that three words, or just ignore it if they don't know and mind their own buisness if in bad mood.

Comment: Thank you @JohnSaunders, I have already been informed about that issue. RononDex, keep calm, everything is under control, even my english. Here is the answer on "Where is the code that provides login in default web site template in visual studio 2010". I found the answer in web config. There is AspNetSqlMembershipProvider inside that interfaces Microsoft membership provider. So, ASP.NET login controls do everything. Here are the details -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.98%29.aspx

Comment: Yeah, except that's not code. It's just the configuration. Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you're looking for is inside of the `Login` control etc. You can't modify the provider that way.

Comment: Thank you, I've just found it myself.